# conflicting requests error while building SDK

Tags: linux, sdk, embedded-linux, yocto

I got the following conflicting requests error while building SDK

I am using sumo branch , and generic core-intel-i7-64 machine configuration.

Running the following command: `bitbake -c populate_sdk core-image-minimal`

Fails at the last step with the following error.

```
ERROR: core-image-minimal-1.0-r0 do_populate_sdk: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/jamal/repotest1/yocto_intel_build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -y -c /home/jamal/repotest1/yocto_intel_build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/poky/2.5/sysroots/corei7-64-poky-linux/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/jamal/repotest1/yocto_intel_build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/poky/2.5/sysroots/corei7-64-poky-linux/etc/yum.repos.d --repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/jamal/repotest1/yocto_intel_build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo --installroot=/home/jamal/repotest1/yocto_intel_build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/poky/2.5/sysroots/corei7-64-poky-linux --setopt=logdir=/home/jamal/repotest1/yocto_intel_build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp --nogpgcheck install lib32-dpkg lib32-libstdc++6 lib32-packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target lib32-libx11-6 lib32-ncurses lib32-libgcc1 lib32-libgnutls30 lib32-libfreetype6 lib32-libc6 run-postinsts libgnutls30 dpkg kernel-devsrc packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target packagegroup-core-boot target-sdk-provides-dummy' returned 1:
Added oe-repo repo from /home/jamal/repotest1/yocto_intel_build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:02 ago on Thu 18 Oct 2018 01:12:30 PM UTC.
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides /usr/bin/python needed by kernel-devsrc-1.0-r0.intel_corei7_64

ERROR: core-image-minimal-1.0-r0 do_populate_sdk: Function failed: do_populate_sdk
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/jamal/repotest1/yocto_intel_build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sdk.11307
ERROR: Task (/home/jamal/repotest1/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_populate_sdk) failed with exit code '1'
```

I found similar error in yocto mailing list, but unable to understand.. Can you please help me to resolve this issue.. Thanks for your time

https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2018-February/039941.html

I have /usr/bin/python in my system

Comment: are you using the latest and compatible versions of the layers?

Comment: Yes.. I am using sumo branches of all versions

Answer (score 0):

Add RDEPENDS to your  kernel-devsrc.bb

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "bc python flex bison ${TCLIBC}-utils"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "openssl-dev util-linux"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "${@bb.utils.contains('ARCH', 'x86', 'elfutils', '', d)}"
```

https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2018-October/042908.html